# GeoJSON not displaying in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

At the following [URL](https://bubinga.co/wp-content/uploads/jsoncounties.min_.js) there is a `FeatureCollection` of US Counties.

I have tried saving the FeatureCollection as a json file with:

`curl "https://bubinga.co/wp-content/uploads/jsoncounties.min_.js" -o "counties.json"`

But in QGIS the file does not display:

[image]

I have also tried importing into QGIS directly with:

[image]

But the same problem occurs.  I am sure I am missing something simple - what could be the issue?

[image]

**EDIT:**

The 10.5 MB file is valid JSON according to jsonlint.com and begins as:

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"state":"AL","counties":67},"counties":[{"name":"Autauga","geographicRegion":"Autauga County, Alabama","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-86.41182,32.4757],[-86.41177,32.46599],[-86.41167,32.45054],[-86.41157,32.44245],[-86.41154,32.43993],[-86.41138,32.42573],[-86.41135,32.42417],[-86.41128,32.42185],[-86.41117,32.41017],[-86.41117,32.40994],[-86.41615,32.4072],[-86.43178,32.40132],[-86.43926,32.40025],[-86.44653,32.40036],[-86.45876,32.40573],[-86.4612,32.40285],[-86.46247,32.38769],[-86.46356,32.37729],[-86.46836,32.37368],[-86.47092,32.37136],[-86.47306,32.36874],[-86.47476,32.36588],[-86.47777,32.36418],[-86.48023,32.36497],[-86.48342,32.36667],[-86.4871,32.36674],[-86.49047,32.36532],[-86.49265,32.36286],[-86.49263,32.36032],[-86.49181,32.35787],[-86.4908,32.35513],[-86.48994,32.35264],[-86.4899,32.34985],[-86.49071,32.34705],[-86.49308,32.34509],[-86.49637,32.34451],[-86.49677,32.34444],[-86.49697,32.34441],[-86.51978,32.34039],[-86.54242,32.36286],[-86.56658,32.37296],[-86.58826,32.36775],[-86.61646,32.38072],[-86.61548,32.40307],[-86.62671,32.40372],[-86.64956,32.40055],[-86.65426,32.37904],[-86.66333,32.36937],[-86.67726,32.35659],[-86.68276,32.35356],[-86.69448,32.35677],[-86.71309,32.36186],[-86.71624,32.36921],[-86.71982,32.3884],[-86.71721,32.40129],[-86.73083,32.40061],[-86.75543,32.38914],[-86.78214,32.39047],[-86.78238,32.37337],[-86.7843,32.32449],[-86.80352,32.30819],[-86.82039,32.3184],[-86.81563,32.3402],[-86.81491,32.3408],[-86.81229,32.34299],[-86.81294,32.36582],[-86.8318,32.38605],[-86.8411,32.41849],[-86.83652,32.4304],[-86.85357,32.43893],[-86.86242,32.43869],[-86.86415,32.44592],[-86.86997,32.4606],[-86.87364,32.47188],[-86.88497,32.48191],[-86.88087,32.48886],[-86.88465,32.49656],[-86.89084,32.5124],[-86.89979,32.52588],[-86.90667,32.53685],[-86.90521,32.54915],[-86.90023,32.55933],[-86.89905,32.57819],[-86.90385,32.59242],[-86.90759,32.60835],[-86.91163,32.62085],[-86.9119,32.63178],[-86.9185,32.64452],[-86.91827,32.65322],[-86.91767,32.66411],[-86.91759,32.66417],[-86.91757,32.66417],[-86.91241,32.66425],[-86.8929,32.66343],[-86.87358,32.66258],[-86.84557,32.66137],[-86.83382,32.66082],[-86.81764,32.66016],[-86.81319,32.66017],[-86.78767,32.66052],[-86.74998,32.66098],[-86.72508,32.66159],[-86.71349,32.66738],[-86.71257,32.70574],[-86.66704,32.70609],[-86.63189,32.70633],[-86.61778,32.70629],[-86.60783,32.70632],[-86.59515,32.70653],[-86.57015,32.70678],[-86.52944,32.70704],[-86.4963,32.7073],[-86.48468,32.7076],[-86.47197,32.70778],[-86.46803,32.70786],[-86.45035,32.70809],[-86.41583,32.70747],[-86.41312,32.70739],[-86.413,32.67818],[-86.41298,32.67406],[-86.41261,32.61636],[-86.4125,32.58942],[-86.41244,32.57816],[-86.41234,32.55023],[-86.41226,32.53344],[-86.41223,32.52876],[-86.4122,32.52668],[-86.4123,32.52082],[-86.41231,32.51273],[-86.41234,32.50446],[-86.4122,32.50006],[-86.41212,32.49626],[-86.41197,32.49065],[-86.41197,32.48577],[-86.41187,32.48112]]]}},`

Comment: Please add a snippet of the file to the question

Comment: You can just click on the link.  Added

Comment: It's quite a big file at 10.5MB, so guess that might be an issue on your system.  It is valid JSON according to http://jsonlint.com.

Comment: What do you get when you paste it into http://geojsonlint.com/ ?

Comment: If I recall, correctly, QGIS may need a variable declared in the GeoJSON file.  Try adding "var counties = " at the head of the JSON text within the file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This JSON file is not a valid [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/). It is a FeatureCollection with 56 Features, but 3251 geometries

A valid GeoJSON Feature format is (with 1 geometry for 1 feature and the fundamental keys/tags `'geometry'` and `'properties'`)

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry":{
 .....
},
"properties": {
....
}
}
```

The Feature format of counties.json is not a valid GeoJSON format (no `'geometry'` tag/key but a list of geometries for 1 feature in `'counties'`).

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"counties": {
    [list of geometries]
},
"properties": {
     ....
}
}
```

Explanation

Opening the file with Python

```
import json
filename = "counties.json"
def load_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         return json.load(f)
geo = load_json(filename)
```

geo is now a Python dictionary with 56 features (`len(geo['features'])`)

If we examine the first feature

```
first = geo['features'][0]
print first.keys()
[u'type', u'properties', u'counties']
print first['type']
Feature
```

There is no tag/key  `'geometry'` therefore the Feature is not valid.

The geometries are in the 'counties' tag/key

```
print len(first['counties'])
67
# tags/keys of the first county
print first['counties'][0].keys()
[u'geometry', u'geographicRegion', u'name']
```

With this JSON file, valid GeoJSON Features would be

```
print first['counties'][0]['geographicRegion'] 
Saipan Municipality, Mariana Islands
feature=dict(type='Feature', properties = first['properties'],geometry=first['counties'][0]['geometry'])
```

[image]

```
print first['counties'][1]['geographicRegion']
Tinian Municipality, Mariana Islands
feature=dict(type='Feature', properties = first['properties'],geometry=first['counties'][1]['geometry'])
```

[image]

etc...

Answer (score 5):

I see the same thing (QGIS 2.18.3)

It's all on one line, so I pretty-printed using python 3.5 at the command line...

```
python3.5 -m json.tool ./counties.geojson | less
```

here's what the first few lines look like when pretty-printed

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "state": "AL",
                "counties": 67
            },
            "counties": [
                {
                    "name": "Autauga",
                    "geographicRegion": "Autauga County, Alabama",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
```

That's certainly valid JSON. Not sure if it's valid GeoJSON, though. I think the geojson spec [was updated fairly recently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946) so it might be worth checking that.

I think it's the structure being nested too deep, each state is a feature, and counties are sub-features (?). I think the json may need to be restructured so that each county is a feature in its own right. In other words, i think the "geometry" should be a sibling of "properties"

That's just a gut feel, but it should be possible in Python/JavaScript to rewrite a new geojson file, by removing the state/county hierarchy, and promoting each county to a feature.